# Organizing buttons in div using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with organizing this gallery to look like this:

[image]

I tried everything I know with positions (absolute and relative), bottoms, margins... but I can't seem to organize it properly.

This popup div needs to occupy 80% of page height and 80% of the page width, and images shouldn't break out of div.

I am not allowed to change HTML or to add CSS. Everything needs to be written inside the JS file.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $('div[title ="London gallery"]').children('img').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
  }).get();
  var description = $('div[title ="London gallery"]').children('p').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();


  $('div[title ="London gallery"]').hide();
  var gallery_lndn = document.createElement('button');
  gallery_lndn.id = 'btn_London';
  gallery_lndn.innerHTML = 'Look at the galery!';
  document.body.appendChild(gallery_lndn);

  document.getElementById('btn_London').onclick = function() {
    show_pictures(images, description);
  }

  function show_pictures(images, description) {
    function popUp() {
      var index = 0;

      var popup = document.createElement('div');
      popup.className = 'popup';
      popup.id = 'div_popup';
      popup.style.background = "#2F4F4F";
      popup.style.position = "absolute";
      popup.style.top = "0px";
      popup.style.left = "0px";
      popup.style.right = "0px";
      popup.style.margin = "100px auto";
      popup.style.height = "80%";
      popup.style.width = "80%";


      var cancelButton = document.createElement('button');
      cancelButton.innerHTML = 'x';
      cancelButton.id = 'btn_cancelButton';
      cancelButton.style.background = "red";
      cancelButton.style.border = "none";
      cancelButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      cancelButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
      cancelButton.style.padding = "15px 20px";
      cancelButton.style.float = "right";
      cancelButton.style.top = "0";
      cancelButton.onclick = function(e) {
        popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup)
      };

      var previousButton = document.createElement('button');
      previousButton.innerHTML = '<<';
      previousButton.style.background = "#32CD32";
      previousButton.style.border = "none";
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      previousButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
      previousButton.style.padding = "15px 32px";
      previousButton.style.position = "absolute";
      previousButton.style.float = "left";
      previousButton.style.bottom = "0";
      previousButton.onclick = function() {
        index = (index == 0) ? images.length - 1 : index - 1;
        console.log(index);
        updateImage();
      }

      var nextButton = document.createElement('button');
      nextButton.innerHTML = '>>';
      nextButton.style.background = "#32CD32";
      nextButton.style.background = "#32CD32";
      nextButton.style.border = "none";
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      nextButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
      nextButton.style.padding = "15px 32px";
      //nextButton.style.position = "absolute";
      nextButton.style.float = "right";
      nextButton.style.bottom = "0";
      nextButton.onclick = function() {
        index = (index == images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
        console.log(index);
        updateImage();
      }

      function updateImage() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = images[index];
        img.style.margin = "auto";
        img.style.position = "relative";
        img.style.display = "block";
        console.log(img);

        $("#div_popup").html("");
        if (index == 0) {
          previousButton.style.background = "#A9A9A9";
          //previousButton.disabled = "true";
        } else if (index == images.length - 1) {
          nextButton.style.background = "#A9A9A9";
          //nextButton.disabled = "true";
        } else {
          //nextButton.disabled = "false";
          //previousButton.disabled = "false";
          previousButton.style.background = "#32CD32";
          nextButton.style.background = "#32CD32";
        }
        popup.appendChild(previousButton);
        popup.appendChild(nextButton);
        popup.appendChild(cancelButton);

        var message = document.createElement('span');
        //message.style.position = "absolute";
        message.style.bottom = "0";
        message.innerHTML = "Picture " + (index + 1) + "/" + images.length + "<br>" + description[index];

        img.onload = function() {
          popup.appendChild(message);
          popup.appendChild(img);
          document.body.appendChild(popup);
        };

      }

      updateImage();
    }
    popUp();
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>London</h1>
  <div class="gallery" title="London gallery">
    <img src="https://cdn.londonandpartners.com/visit/general-london/areas/river/76709-640x360-houses-of-parliament-and-london-eye-on-thames-from-above-640.jpg">
            <p data-target="https://cdn.londonandpartners.com/visit/general-london/areas/river/76709-640x360-houses-of-parliament-and-london-eye-on-thames-from-above-640.jpg">
    Description 1.
    </p>  
    <img src="https://news.itu.int/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/london-min-e1530887248858.jpg">
    <p data-target="https://news.itu.int/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/london-min-e1530887248858.jpg">
    Description 2.
    </p>    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aurora, the easiest way for us to help you would be to replicate your issue in a codepen so that we can play with it. Your question is however very general and does not tackle a single issue but a whole lot of questions at the same time.

Comment: @mikegross I've done you one better and used [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so you can see it work on Stack Overflow and use Copy snippet to answer to "fork" the snippet to answer one of the questions ;).

Comment: @aurora, if you could please update the image reference with the path to an image available online (perhaps from a stock photo site that allows hot linking, or from a purpose-built dummy image site), that would make it much easier to see what your code is attempting to do.

Comment: I edited it. Should be fine now!

Comment: Thanks @mikegross, didn't know about code snippet :)

Comment: Achievable. Buttons can be positioned with js as you required.
But, for proper solution, actually the html structure should be  - 
Inside popup there should be one div and Images and buttons should be inside that container div.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the button positions according to the image. Call below method inside the updateImage method just before closing.

```
function updatePositions(){
// absolute position for all buttons
$('#div_popup > button').css({'position': 'absolute', 'float':'none', 'z-index': 1});


// get image bottom position
let buttonTopPos = ($('#div_popup > img').offset().top + $('#div_popup > img').height()) - $('#div_popup').offset().top + 20;

// get image bottom left position
let buttonLeftPos = 0;
if($('#div_popup').width() > $('#div_popup > img').width()){
    buttonLeftPos = ($('#div_popup').width() - $('#div_popup > img').width())/2
}else{
   $('#div_popup > img').css({'min-width':'100%', 'max-width':'100%'});
}

// image overflow will be hidden
$('#div_popup').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// Back button position
$('#div_popup > button:nth-child(1)').css({'top': buttonTopPos, 'bottom':'auto', 'left': buttonLeftPos +'px'})

// Next button position
$('#div_popup > button:nth-child(2)').css({'top': buttonTopPos, 'bottom':'auto', 'left': (buttonLeftPos + $('#div_popup > img').width()) - 90})

// cancel button position
$('#div_popup > button:nth-child(3)').css({'top': 0, 'right': 0, left: 'auto'});

// description position
$('#div_popup > span').css({'position': 'absolute','top': buttonTopPos, 'bottom':'auto', 'left': buttonLeftPos + 90, 'width': $('#div_popup > img').width() - 90 - 90, 'text-align': 'center'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a layout that approximates the sample, above. For convenience, this uses JavaScript to add a `<style>` element to the `<head>`.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const myCSS =
    '    body {\n' +
    '      width:100vw;\n' +
    '      height:100vh;\n' +
    '      position:relative\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .gallery {\n' +
    '      background-color: darkblue;\n' +
    '      width: 80%;\n' +
    '      height: 80%;\n' +
    '      position: absolute;\n' +
    '      top: 10%;\n' +
    '      left: 10%;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .img-wrapper {\n' +
    '      background-color: transparent;\n' +
    '      width: calc(100% - 120px);\n' +
    '      height: calc(100% - 160px);\n' +
    '      margin: 60px;\n' +
    '      overflow-y: hidden;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .img-wrapper img {\n' +
    '      width: 100%;\n' +
    '      height: auto;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .btn1 {\n' +
    '      width: 120px;\n' +
    '      height: 60px;\n' +
    '      position: absolute;\n' +
    '      left: 60px;\n' +
    '      bottom: 30px;\n' +
    '      background-color: #999;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .btn2 {\n' +
    '      width: 120px;\n' +
    '      height: 60px;\n' +
    '      position: absolute;\n' +
    '      right: 60px;\n' +
    '      bottom: 30px;\n' +
    '      background-color: #999;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .btn-close {\n' +
    '      width: 80px;\n' +
    '      height: 40px;\n' +
    '      position: absolute;\n' +
    '      right: 0;\n' +
    '      top: 0;\n' +
    '      background-color: #999;\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '    .caption {\n' +
    '      width: calc(100% - 409px);\n' +
    '      height: 60px;\n' +
    '      position: absolute;\n' +
    '      left: 192px;\n' +
    '      bottom: 30px;\n' +
    '      color: white;\n' +
    '      border: 1px dashed #aaa;\n' +
    '      text-align: center;\n' +
    '      padding: 0 12px;\n' +
    '      overflow: hidden;\n' +
    '    }\n';
  const myStyle = document.createElement('style');
  myStyle.id = 'myCSS';
  myStyle.innerHTML = myCSS;
  document.head.appendChild(myStyle);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="https://cdn.londonandpartners.com/visit/general-london/areas/river/76709-640x360-houses-of-parliament-and-london-eye-on-thames-from-above-640.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="btn1">.btn1</div>
    <div class="btn2">.btn2</div>
    <div class="caption">.caption</div>
    <div class="btn-close">.btn-close</div>
  </div>
</body>
```